# Aumentar y disminuir tamaño de títulos desde JS

Tags: javascript

¿Como puedo añadir una función en JS la cual me permita aumentar y disminuir el tamaño de las fuentes de la pagina desde JavasScript?.

He probado con esto pero no me funciono para subir y bajar el tamaño de las fuentes.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) =>{
  if (event.key == 'a'|| event.key == 'A'){
    DIVVACIO.style.fontSize = "+ 10px";
  }
  else if (event.key == 'b'|| event.key == 'B'){
    DIVVACIO.style.fontSize = "- 10px";
  }
})
```

Comment: Solo quita el `+` y `-` del `fontSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder aumentar o disminuir el tamaño, primero necesitas obtener el tamaño actual.
Para esto podes usar [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const DIVVACIO = document.getElementById('div');

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  // Obtenemos los estilos
  const compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(DIVVACIO);
  // Obtenemos el tamaño de la fuente como número
  let fontSize = parseFloat(compStyles.getPropertyValue('font-size'));
  
  if (event.key == 'a' || event.key == 'A') {
    // Incrementamos el tamaño en 10px
    DIVVACIO.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 10) + 'px';
  } else if (event.key == 'b' || event.key == 'B') {
    // Decrementamos el tamaño en 10px
    DIVVACIO.style.fontSize = (fontSize - 10) + 'px';
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="div">Mi texto</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !!

Comment: @Seph86, si te sirvió, considera votar la respuesta y/o marcara como aceptada. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No agregues ese **+10** o **-10** al modificar el tamaño simplemente dale el tamaño fijo, el estilo no acepta ese caracter `+` o `-` que agregas, es como si escribieras `font-size: +10px` lo que es incorrecto solo deberia ser `font-size: 10px`, o simplemente recupera antes el tamaño de fuente para poder sumarle el tamaño como lo hace *@Marcos* en su ejemplo.

```js
const DIVVACIO = document.getElementById('mi-div');
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) =>{
    if (event.key == 'a'|| event.key == 'A'){
        DIVVACIO.style.fontSize = "30px";
    }
    else if (event.key == 'b'|| event.key == 'B'){
         DIVVACIO.style.fontSize = "8px";
    }
})
```

```html
<div id='mi-div'>
Mi texto de prueba
</div>
```